# Are there methods for quantifying certainty in a non-logistic regression model?

Tags: regression, probability, predictive-models, calibration

I've been looking into certainty and how to calibrate classification models such that their predicted probability correlates well with their actual accuracy. I was wondering if such methods existed for continuous regression models. Is there a way to get a prediction from a cont regression model and also get the model's certainty?

Comment: Model certainty can be evaluated via confidence/prediction intervals, but with big data the variance will be less important than the bias.  Hence, you can have high precision and still be very wrong.

Comment: @DemetriPananos what do you mean by "bias" in this context?

Comment: He means in the sense of the bias–variance trade-off.